# Deploy Django Application HTTPD

Tags: django, apache

I wanted to deploy my Django Application and tried to achieve that with **Whitenoise** ,
but this last one only serves my static files, now I need to serve my media files.
I want to use **Apache** ( **HTTPD** in Manjaro/Arch) to do that but couldn't figure it out, after trying several tutos.

Here's my config :

*httpd.conf*:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/chemsouh/dev/rci/rci/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonHome /home/chemsouh/dev/rci
WSGIPythonPath /home/chemsouh/dev/rci/rci

<Directory /home/chemsouh/dev/rci/rci>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

*settings.py*:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media-directory/'
MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "media-serve/")
```

I also tried this:

in my *httpd-vhosts.conf*:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    ServerAdmin RCI
    DocumentRoot "/home/chemsouh/dev/rci/media-serve"
    ServerName rci.co
    ServerAlias www.rci.co    
    ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/dummy-host.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/dummy-host.example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

in my *httpd.conf*:

```
DocumentRoot "/home/chemsouh/dev/rci/media-serve"
<Directory "/home/chemsouh/dev/rci/media-serve">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And I got this *My media directory that I want to serve*

[image: My media directory that I want to serve]

Here's my project Tree:
$pwd gave */home/chemsouh/dev/rci*

[image: project tree]

**N.B** I use:

Apache 2.4
Django 2.0.6
in settings there is settings.py

Comment: can you add your project tree and your project path ?

Comment: @ChihebNexus I just did sir.

Comment: And the version of apache ?

Comment: @ChihebNexus I updated the post

Comment: Have you read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your django project architecture is strange to me and also i'm not using `Manjaro`. In my answer i'm using `Ubuntu 16.04` you can reproduce it using `Manjaro`.

Besides of this, here is a simple tutorial of how you can deploy a django project using `Apache` and `Python3+`.

First of all, you need to install `Apache2` and `mod_wsgi` for Python3:

```
$> sudo apt update
$> sudo apt install apache2
$> sudo apt install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
```

Then, i suppose that your Django project is under `/var/www/html` directory and it is similar to this architecutre:

```
$> tree -I '__pycache__|migrations'
.
└── deploy_django
    ├── deploy_django
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── settings.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   └── wsgi.py
    ├── django_app
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── apps.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   └── views.py
    ├── manage.py
    ├── media
    └── static
```

Then, you need to configure your `Apache` virtual host:

```
$> sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

And add those lines between `<virtualHost>` and `</virtualHost>`:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess django \ # Your Django's project process name
python-home=/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ \ # Python3 dist packages OR even better use your virtualenv's python path
python-path=/var/www/html/deploy_django # Path of your Django project folder
WSGIProcessGroup django # Your django's Process Group
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/deploy_django/deploy_django/wsgi.py # Where is your WSGI File 
<Directory /var/www/html/deploy_django/deploy_django>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
Alias /media/ /var/www/html/deploy_django/media/ # Media dir
Alias /static/ /var/www/html/deploy_django/static/ # Static dir

<Directory /var/www/html/deploy_django/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/deploy_django/media>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And finally:

```
$> service apache2 restart
```

And open `127.0.0.1` in your browser and everything should be okay.

Besides of this, if you encounter some errors, you can check `Apache's logs` in the file `/var/log/apache2/error.log` or under the directory `/var/log/apache2`